# How to Execute Event on VSTO Add In Once Outlook is loaded C#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

How do I execute an event after the Outlook application is fully loaded. I tried to execute some code when the C# VSTO addin startup event fires but I am looking to run a script after the application is finished loading. Any ideas?

```
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        //Doesn't make sense to add script here because outlook is still not finished loading
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
        //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of "fully loaded" and why do you need that event?

Comment: I want to create Categorization tags in outlook from the VSTO add in automatically when outlook starts, but I believe (perhaps incorrectly) that this needs to happen once the application is in some sort of "Startup complete" state. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean you need to access the global categories list? You should be bale to that whenever your addin pleases.

Comment: Yes the global categories list. However, I don't believe that you can access during the addin startup event. ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

Comment: Have you actually tried that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Startup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/application-startup-event-outlook) event of the Application class is fired when Microsoft Outlook is starting, but after all add-ins have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity and I use the stack everyday but have never posted.
I maintain a VSTO Add-in for Visio which has common relevance to other Office Add-ins...

I too am trying to run code in the Add-in Startup Event: ThisAddIn_Startup.

this.Application.ActiveDocument.DocumentChanged += MyEventHandler;

I kept getting an exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: o

What I found is that, although the add-in is loaded there are no open documents:
this.Application.ActiveDocument is null

I changed my event handler assignment to:
this.Application.DocumentOpened += MyHigherLayerEventHandler;

reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019#AccessingDocuments
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/events-in-office-projects?view=vs-2019
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.addinbase.requestcomaddinautomationservice?view=vsto-2017
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/architecture-of-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019

THEN -- (this part might need to be in a separate topic, idk, but)
I noticed that the event was firing twice. As a matter of fact both ThisAddIn_Startup --and-- ThisAddIn_Shutdown fire 2 times. I spent about 10 hours this weekend trying to solve this issue. I even added an increment counter with a messagebox : the messagebox popped up 2 times and the counter did NOT increment.

The problem / solution turned out to be registry entries.
If you are anything like me as a developer your machine probably has more than a couple of test projects and maybe some old abandoned ones. I had an older Add-in of the same manifest file name but a different repository location. After a couple of find searches through the registry

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Visio\Addins\TEAM_VSTO  <-- i deleted this registry entry

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Visio\Addins\NewAddinName

*presto, magic, event only fires 1 time *facepalm
Anyway, I hope this helps someone.