# Outlook: detect when "Send/Receive" has finished after startup

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am developing an outlook plugin in C#.

I want to be able to detect when outlook has finished the "send/receive" option after startup, so that I can then run operations on the received mail items.

What I have tried so far:

- Manually calling `Application.Session.SendAndReceive()` on startup.
  This runs fine, but the method returns before the send/receive is complete, which is the opposite of what I want
- Overriding Application.NewMail and Application.NewMailEx - neither of these trigger as one might hope at startup (NewMailEx doesn't fire at all, NewMail is unreliable)
- Calling `NameSpace.SyncObjects.AppFolders.Start();` and registering the `SyncObjects.AppFolders.SyncEnd` event - this event fires before outlook has finished downloading mail
- Iterating through `NameSpace.SyncObjects`, calling `Start()`, and registering `SyncEnd` - this method doesn't fire at all.

What is a solution here which will work depenably?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a hack to detect when syncing has finished; namely to override `Application.Reminders.BeforeReminderShow` as DWE suggests in [this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65855485/3646777)
This event (in my testing) always fires after outlook syncing has finished.
Then, in order to make sure the reminder window fires, you add a new reminder at startup, and then hide the reminder again within Reminders_BeforeReminderShow

The code then being something like:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    private ReminderCollectionEvents_Event reminders; //don't delete, or else the GC will break things

    AppointmentItem hiddenReminder;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //other stuff
            hiddenReminder = (AppointmentItem)Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); //add a new silent reminder to trigger Reminders_BeforeReminderShow.This method will be triggered after send/receive is finished
            hiddenReminder.Start = DateTime.Now;
            hiddenReminder.Subject = "Autogenerated Outlook Plugin Reminder";
            hiddenReminder.Save();

            reminders = Application.Reminders;
            reminders.BeforeReminderShow += Reminders_BeforeReminderShow;
    }

    private void Reminders_BeforeReminderShow(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        if (hiddenReminder == null) return;

        bool anyVisibleReminders = false;
        for (int i = Application.Reminders.Count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if (Application.Reminders[i].Caption == "Autogenerated Outlook Plugin Reminder") //|| Application.Reminders[i].Item == privateReminder
            {
                Application.Reminders[i].Dismiss();
            }
            else
            {
                if (Application.Reminders[i].IsVisible)
                {
                    anyVisibleReminders = true;
                }
            }
        }

        Cancel = !anyVisibleReminders;
        hiddenReminder?.Delete();
        hiddenReminder = null;
            //your custom code here
    }

}
```

Yup, this is very kludgy, but that's the nature of working with outlook, and I haven't seen any free alternative which can actually claim to work reliably, whereas this works in all of the use cases I've tried it in. So that's a hit I'm willing to take to get a working solution.

Comment: At first this didn't seem like it was working -- but then it kicked in after about 30-45 seconds for me... just had to be patient.  Worked like a charm: all folders fully updated without resorting to a timer or other even-more-kludgy solution.   And hey -- just because you answered your own question doesn't mean the answer isn't valid -- go ahead and mark it as the accepted Answer.

Comment: Also -- important to remember to unsubscribe from the BeforeReminderShow event, to keep it from triggering each time any actual reminders are about to show: `reminders.BeforeReminderShow -= Reminders_BeforeReminderShow;`